# MatrixGrid Control - How to set the image between the Axis?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I am trying to set an image, as seen on the example that the Gx documentation provides ("Matrix Class" article):
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Matrix+Class,

Can't find the property... Can you please help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control does not have a property for that, i think that this image was placed there using a [canvas control](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?22452).

With the canvas control you will be able to overlay controls. In order to achieve this you could put the grid and the image inside a canvas and set the *ZOrder property of the grid lower than the z order of the image.

Width and Height properties of the grid must be 100%, and the position of the image over the grid comes from the values of the Left and Top properties.

*it specifies the stack order of a control.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please provide more details on how would it be possible to accomplish this? Can't imagine how to apply canvas or transformations on something that, in runtime, is totally different from what I have in design (a simple grid with a layout var in it).